# Drawable icons on route not pinned at base

Tags: android, mapbox

I am using drawable images for marker icons on a route. The base of the image does not appear at the point but rather more in the middle.
Can this be addressed?

[image: Route]

```
Double latitude = new Double(getString(R.string.sagrada_latitude));
Double longitude = new Double(getString(R.string.sagrada_longitude));
final Position origin = Position.fromCoordinates(longitude, latitude);

latitude = new Double(getString(R.string.mataro_latitude));
longitude = new Double(getString(R.string.mataro_longitude));
final Position destination = Position.fromCoordinates(longitude, latitude); 

// Create an Icon object for the marker to use
IconFactory iconFactory = IconFactory.getInstance(this);
Drawable iconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.green_pin);
final Icon greenPinIcon = iconFactory.fromDrawable(iconDrawable);
iconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.red_pin);
final Icon redPinIcon = iconFactory.fromDrawable(iconDrawable);

// Setup the MapView
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        map = mapboxMap;

        // Add origin and destination to the map
        LatLng originLatLng = (new LatLng(origin.getLatitude(), origin.getLongitude()));
        mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(originLatLng)
                .title("Origin")
                .snippet("current location: (" + origin.getLatitude() + ", " + origin.getLongitude() + ")")
                .icon(greenPinIcon));

        Log.d(TAG, "getMapAsync(): destination: (" + destination.getLatitude() + ", " + destination.getLongitude() + ")");
        LatLng destinationLatLng = (new LatLng(destination.getLatitude(), destination.getLongitude()));
        mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(destinationLatLng)
                .title("Destination")
                .snippet("destination: (" + destination.getLatitude() + ", " + destination.getLongitude() + ")")
                .icon(redPinIcon));
            mapboxMap.easeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 50), 5000);

            // Get route from API
            try {
                getRoute(origin, destination);
            }
            catch (ServicesException servicesException) {
                Log.e(TAG, servicesException.toString());
                servicesException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void getRoute(Position origin, Position destination) throws ServicesException {

    client = new MapboxDirections.Builder()
            .setOrigin(origin)
            .setDestination(destination)
            .setProfile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_CYCLING)
            .setAccessToken(MapboxAccountManager.getInstance().getAccessToken())
            .build();

    client.enqueueCall(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
            // You can get the generic HTTP info about the response
            Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
            if (response.body() == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                return;
            } else if (response.body().getRoutes().size() < 1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                return;
            }

            // Print some info about the route
            currentRoute = response.body().getRoutes().get(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "Distance: " + currentRoute.getDistance());
            Double km = currentRoute.getDistance() / 1000;
            // there are 4 digits to the right of the decimal, make it 2
            String kilometers = km.toString();
            int index = kilometers.lastIndexOf(".");
            kilometers = kilometers.substring(0, index + 3);
            Toast.makeText(
                    DirectionsActivity.this,
                    "Route is " + kilometers + " kilometers",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Draw the route on the map
            drawRoute(currentRoute);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(DirectionsActivity.this, "Error: " + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

A side question ... the Position.fromCoordinates method:

```
private Position(double longitude, double latitude, double altitude)
```

takes the arguments in order of longitude then latitude, not latitude then longitude as one might expect. Why?

Edit:
Changed `MarkerOptions` to `MarkerViewOptions` and the icons moved even further away. Also tried `.anchor(0,0)` which had no effect.

[image: MarkerViewOptions]

Also, with default Icons (which are off):

[image: Default Icons]

Icon:
[image: Red Pin]

```
// Mapbox dependencies  
compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.1@aar') {  
    transitive = true  
}  
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-directions:1.0.0@aar'){  
    transitive=true  
}  
compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:1.3.1@aar') {  
    transitive = true  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add padding to the bottom of the marker icon png or a better option would be using `MarkerViewOptions()` instead. They give more options then the GL markers your currently using including anchor. By default the anchoring is center bottom. So one of you markers would look like this:

```
mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerViewOptions()
            .position(destinationLatLng)
            .title("Destination")
            .snippet("destination: (" + destination.getLatitude() + ", " + destination.getLongitude() + ")")
            .icon(redPinIcon));
```

To answer your other question, why position takes in longitude, latitude in that order, many of the Mapbox APIs consume coordinates in that order. The bigger question is why does the `Position` object exist when `LatLng` is found already in the Map SDK? This is because the objects would conflict since they are found in separate SDKs yet are typically used together. It is something we look forward to changing in the near future.

**EDIT:** first you need to remove the `mapbox-android-directions`, this is an old, non supported, SDK we have deprecated. Mapbox Android Services (MAS) is it's replacement and uses Mapbox Directions V5. Use [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/directions/) which shows how to properly make a directions call using MAS and add the markers to the map. Using the coordinates found in your question, the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I suspect (long,lat) was chosen because that it is Cartesian (x,y). Tempting, but one must resist. Sounds like `Position` is to be deprecated or changed at some point, so good on you guys.  
  
Adding padding to the image would, as you hint, be a kluge. This is because the amount that the position of the image is off varies with the scale, so the padding would need to vary as well.  
  
I tried `MarkerViewOptions` but that didn't help (see edit).

Comment: Can you please also add the png file you are using for the marker icon? `.anchoring(0,0)` would be anchoring the image in the top left corner.

Comment: Add png file and another image.

Comment: Make sure you are either using the latest beta version, `4.2.0-beta.4` or `4.1.1`. We previously had a marker anchoring issue that has since been resolved.

Comment: Just add dependencies to question. Are these correct?

Comment: Thanks, I've removed `mapbox-android-directions` now. You say "Use this example ...". I'm not sure what example you are talking about. Did you intend to include a link?

Comment: Thanks. With the default markers, it now displays correctly. With my icons, it still is off in the same way. If I understand the anchor parameters correctly, `.anchor((float)0.5, 1)` would place the bottom middle of the icon at the point. This doesn't happen. In fact, I've tried various values and `.anchor` seems to have no effect at all. Are you able to position an icon-png correctly?